# Recompile a Fortran function using getprocaddress from 32bits to 64bits

Tags: fortran, 32bit-64bit

I'm using `GetProcAddress` in a function.
It compiled when I was in `32bits`.
I moved to `64bits` and now I get this error while I compile:

```
error #6284: There is no matching specific function for this generic function reference.   [GETPROCADDRESS]
```

How may I resolve this?
Do I need to call another library? (I use `DFWIN` and `DFLIB`)

Comment: Where does GetProcAddress come from? Is there a generic interface created by you? Or do you use an interface from some module? Maybe from DFWIN - what is it, where does it come from? Please show the relevant code. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Please also learn to use the formatting. Do not put spaces befor.double colons and question marks and do not use greetings, your name is already put below your post automatically. But your code is most important, some people already started to downvote your question, try to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

GetProcAddress is a Windows API function. The first argument is a handle to the "module" - usually the return from LoadLibrary. If you have declared the handle argument as just INTEGER or INTEGER*4, it will be the wrong size on a 64-bit platform and you'll get the error you saw.

The fix is to declare the handle variable as:

INTEGER(HANDLE)

where HANDLE is a constant declared by the Fortran Windows API module. This will ensure that it is the correct size on either 32-bit or 64-bit platforms.